# IIS returning a page in response.responseText

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

A user attempted to upload a file that was too large (70MB for a single PDF page) and the system errored out. This is correct and expected behavior, however in the response.responseText (in a jQuery AJAX call) instead of just being the message, it was raw text of an entire html page, cut off at a certain point, which I believe coincides with the default style of IIS error pages.

I do not want to increase the limit of the file size to allow the file to come through, but I do wish to make it to where response.responseText just returns the message (effectively, what's between the < title > < /title > tags).

I attempted to set breakpoints in the upload.ashx file to see if I could find where this was happening, but it never gets that far (if it is a normal file, these breakpoints hit). Which is fine, I'm okay with IIS gatekeeping (I imagine if I try to bypass IIS for handling it, the file is going to get uploaded to the server and then rejected. Plus, lose out on just letting IIS configuration handle this), but I don't want to return an entire page if possible.

To my mind, the resolution I see is to see if response.responseText contains DOCTYPE and if so, scrape what is inside the title tag, but I feel like there may be a more by the book way of doing this?

[image]

edit: I did see where someone recommended setting existingResponse="PassThrough" on the httpErrors section of web.config, but when I did this the responseText just became blank and it still didn't touch breakpoints so I don't think this is achieving what I'm after.

Comment: Do you mean to display part of the html content? but this cannot be done in iis.

Comment: Yeah, basically just want the error message returned as currently I'm alerting the response's responseText. I think I may just need to scrape the contents within the title and call it a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the best way to handle, but seems to work in this case so just running with it:

changed:

```
error: function (response) {
  alert(response.responseText);
}
```

to:

```
error: function (response) {
  var titleIndex = response.responseText.indexOf('<title>');
  var titleEndIndex = response.responseText.indexOf('</title>');
  var message = response.responseText.substr(titleIndex + 7, titleEndIndex - titleIndex - 7);
  alert(message);
}
```

which returns "IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large" in this particular instance.